# ClassNotFoundException when trying to run lite version that references library

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, android-library

I had my main project working and finished.  I started researching how to make a lite/pro version and now everything is messing up.  I made the main project an `Android Library` which is named `BibleTrivia` and now have two other projects referencing it which are named `BibleTriviaLite` and `BibleTriviaPro`.  I thought I had it all working but when I try to run the lite version, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when it tries to find the first activity which is the `SplashScreen`.  The `SplashScreen` is the same for the lite and pro versions so I have it in the library project.

My question is how to get this structure correct so I can run my lite and pro versions without this exception.

I have showed my `LogCat` output and my file structure below.  Let me know if you need anything further.

LogCat

```
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite/matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.SplashScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.SplashScreen" on path: /data/app/matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite-1.apk
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.SplashScreen" on path: /data/app/matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite-1.apk
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-09 02:10:52.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4706):     ... 11 more
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is the beginning to my lite `AndroidManifest`.  The `LogCat` is saying `ClassNotFoundException` for the SplashScreen activity so it it reading the below manifest but then is unable to find the SplashScreen launcher activity.

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_lite"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".About"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    ...
    ...more activities...
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: You're looking for class matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.SplashScreen but in your screenshot SplashScreen seems to be in matt.lyons.bibletrivia package.

Comment: How exactly did you **make** the lite version?

Comment: @pabrantes Shouldn't it be trying to find the SplashScreen from the library since it is referencing it?

Comment: @greenkode Like any other project, like this:  ````File > New > Project > ...```` with no activities created for it initially.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @Matt: It can find it from the library if you specify the correct package name. Most probably the definition of your SlapshScreen activity still has the old package name instead of the new one, you must fix that in order to work.

Comment: The library package name is ````matt.lyons.bibletrivia```` and the package name for the lite version is ````matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite````.  The SplashScreen activity is in the library so I put the package name at the top of the SplashScreen.java file is ````matt.lyons.bibletrivia````.  Is that correct?  Or should I put the package name as ````matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite```` even though the actual SplashScreen.java activity resides inside the library project.

And the reason it is in the library project is because I want that SplashScreen to work for the lite and pro versions.

Comment: But now that I think of it, I would not want to change the package name of the SplashScreen activity that is in BibleTrivia to BibleTriviaLite because I want the pro version (BibleTriviaPro) to also read the SplashScreen.  I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: Updated my opening post to include a snippet from the lite (matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite) manifest.

Comment: Where defining the splashscreen activity change <activity android:name="**.SplashScreen**" into <activity android:name="**matt.lyons.bibletrivia.SplashScreen**". In the manifest you defined that your base package is "matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite" so defining an activity as ".SplashScreen" you're telling to look for class matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.SplashScreen. But the FQN for the class is actually matt.lyons.bibletrivia.SplashScreen, hence the ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Perfect - working now.  If you want, place that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Matt: Glad I could help, answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As original postal suggested, I'm posting my comments has an answer since it fixed the problem.

In the image you posted I can see that SplashScreen Activity class is in the package **matt.lyons.bibletrivia**. With this information, along with your manifest file I can conclude the following:

1. You're defining your default package as **matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite** do to your *package* attribute in the manifest file
2. You're defining SplashScreen activity as if it was in the default package, because you're defining the activity as **android:name=".SplashScreen"**. This results in looking for the class matt.lyons.bibletrivite.lite.SplashScreen, which does not exist.

To fix your problem you just have to define your SplashScreen activity with the full class name, meaning:

```
android:name=".SplashScreen"
```

Should be substituted by

```
android:name="matt.lyons.bibletrivite.SplashScreen"
```

And everything should work just fine.